# nine-patch images not working in android lollipop and cordova splashscreen plugin?

Tags: cordova, android-5.0-lollipop, nine-patch

I'm developing an app in Cordova (4.2.0) for Android. I want to use a nine-patch png image for my Splashscreen (plugin v.0.3.5). I prepared such image using ADT draw9patch tool without trouble.

I've noticed it works as expected in my Android 4.0 phone (mdpi image), but not in my Nexus Android 5.0.1 phone (xhdpi image). The splashscreen gets deformed in Android 5.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Is there a workaround?

**UPDATE**
I delved into Splashscreen Plugin's code. On version 0.3.5 version, in the file `platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova`, one can change the line and put TranslucentDecor in the theme, or any other available in the API that puts the on-screen navigation as translucent. Then the proportions of the screen are preserved and the image is not distorted. 
Im referring to this line:

```
// Create and show the dialog 
splashDialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_NoActionBar_TranslucentDecor );
```

It is not exactly what I expected, but at least the splashscreen does not get distorted.

**I would like to leave the on-screen navigations *visible* and *non-transparent* and use a working nine-patch image.**

Comment: We have the same issue but didn't solve it

Comment: @shammon I delved into Splashscreen Plugin's code. On version 0.3.5 version you can change the line and put TranslucentDecor in the theme, or any other available in the API that puts the on-screen navigation as translucent. Then the proportions of the screen are preserved and the image is not distorted. Im referring to this line:
    // Create and show the dialog
    splashDialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_NoActionBar_TranslucentDecor );